# Wix 4 - Public Documents property not working

Tags: visual-studio, properties, wix, wix4, heatwave

First time working with WIX. I needed a simple deployment solution with an msi package for a small desktop application.

I work on a Windows 10 pro station, Visual Studio 2022 , installed Heatwave's extension for Wix 4, started a new "msi package" project and I got the WixToolset.Util package (4.0.1) from Nuget in order to use the **"WIX_DIR_COMMON_DOCUMENTS"** property for some of the apps files that need to be in the *C:\Users\Public\Documents* folder.

**The problem:** What ever I tried, I continuously get the following error when I try to build.
"*Error WIX0094 The identifier 'Property:WIX_DIR_COMMON_DOCUMENTS' could not be found. Ensure you have typed the reference correctly and that all the necessary inputs are provided to the linker."*
Removing the property and it's references, the project builds perfectly.

**What I tried:** I checked for typos, I uninstalled and reinstalled the packages, I changed the source code schema URIs because by default it uses Microsoft's and not wixtoolset, cleaning the project, restarting VS, many other tricks I found online, nothing.... I have also installed the WixToolset.UI package for the UI and it works fine so my guess is that it's not a generic package installation conflict.

chatGPT suggestions for the problem were not that helpful since it's dataset was built prior to the release of Wix 4 but it did help as per providing a backup solution: creating a custom dll with a function inside to return the folder needed and call this function on a custom action in the installer.

Not bad, but I don't want to just go for it, since I believe I probably have overlooked something and hopefully someone will point it out.

Thx in advance!

Edit: I am sharing the code from the main wxs project file as requested.

```
    <Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
 xmlns:ui="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui"
 xmlns:util="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/util">    
  <Package Name="App" 
           Manufacturer="Company" 
           Version="1.0.0.0" 
           UpgradeCode="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
           Compressed="yes">
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeError)" />        
    <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="$(var.ProjectDir)\Eula.rtf" />
    <PropertyRef Id="WIX_DIR_COMMON_DOCUMENTS" />
    <ui:WixUI
        Id="WixUI_Minimal"
        InstallDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"
    />
    <Feature Id="Main">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ABC" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ABCD" />
    </Feature>    
  </Package>
</Wix>
```

**Update**: I tried the same thing on another workstation, new wix msi package project, nothing but the WixToolSet.Util package 4.0.2 from nuget and the WIX_DIR_COMMON_DOCUMENTS property declared and I get the same exact error on build. What do I miss??

Comment: Error messages without example source code are very hard to diagnose.

Comment: I just posted my code.

Comment: @rob-mensching, I followed your channel on youtube and started watching the Deployement Dojo series... They are pure gold! Even though I ended up using a hardcoded property for my issue, you guys are obviously pushing through with the new wix 4.0 platform. Kudos! I am sharing the link here for anyone who might be interested in wix 4.0: [link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDlzbQXIs18slmqmdlS10_de_Cps-QRg6)