# WiX 4 - How to install a subfolder and files to "C:\Users\Public\Documents"

Tags: wix, wix4

I tried various things and read several posts, but I cannot figure it out.

I'm using **WiX 4.0.4** (important: *not* WiX 3) and I want to create a sub-folder named "MySubFolder" in "C:\Users\Public\Documents" and copy a file there (say MyFile.txt) during installation. Both the file and the folder shall be deleted when uninstalling.

In this related Stackoverflow question someone asks for how to deal with the "WIX_DIR_COMMON_DOCUMENTS" property to handle that, but there's no aswer (at least I can't see it): [Wix 4 - Public Documents property not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77099155/wix-4-public-documents-property-not-working)

I even don't know how I can hard-wire that directory, though - however - that's not the solution I'd prefer. I'm totally confused about  and  and  etc. elements.

Can someone please provide a Demo?

Thanks so much!